# Remove last numbers only from a string value with mixed alpha numerical values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for help to only remove the last numbers from a string value in SQL Server.

Any number prior to the last alpha character can remain.

example:- abcd-1-efgh12

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is with a combination of patindex, reverese, len and left.

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
Col nvarchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable(Col) VALUES
('abcd-1-efgh12'),
('adc-1-def1'),
('a1-1-a1'),
-- Added some edge cases: 
('123-fa'), -- last chars are not digits
('asdf'), -- no digits at all
('123'); -- no non-digit chars at all
```

The query:

```
SELECT Col, LEFT(Col, LEN(Col)+1-PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Col)))
FROM MyTable
```

results:

| Col | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| abcd-1-efgh12 | abcd-1-efgh |
| adc-1-def1 | adc-1-def |
| a1-1-a1 | a1-1-a |
| 123-fa | 123-fa |
| asdf | asdf |
| 123 | 123 |

Note: in case the string contains only digits it will not be changed.

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/D5-Oypac)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all numbers from the end of a string in SQL Server, you can use a method that involves checking each character from the end until a non-numeric character is found. Given that SQL Server doesn't support regex directly for this purpose, we'll adapt our approach to utilize a combination of RIGHT, PATINDEX, and a loop or a recursive CTE for a more robust solution:

```
DECLARE @MyString NVARCHAR(100) = 'abc-eg-hij124';
DECLARE @NotNumericPos INT = 0;

-- Find the position of the first non-numeric character from the right
SET @NotNumericPos = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(@MyString));

-- If there are no non-numeric characters (i.e., the string is fully numeric), return an empty string
-- Otherwise, return the string up to the first non-numeric character from the right
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN @NotNumericPos = 0 THEN '' 
         ELSE LEFT(@MyString, LEN(@MyString) - @NotNumericPos + 1) 
       END AS Result;
```

This script sets @NotNumericPos to the position of the first non-numeric character from the end of the string (by reversing it and searching from the beginning). It then checks if such a position exists (@NotNumericPos > 0). If the entire string is numeric, it could return an empty string or the full string as needed.